# How do I get Cors to work with JavaScript - fix?

Tags: cors

I can submit successfully with cURL on Command Line and get a response. Not so with JavaScipt in a browser. I'm rusty on JavaScript but really need this to work with several pieces of selectable data and to submit with a voice audio sample which IBM says won't work with cURL, just JavaScript. No audio is submitted in this code below just to keep it simple. I have access to the Github SDK but haven't found an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

The working cURL code is:
`curl -X POST -u "apikey:blahblahblah" --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset: utf-8" --header "Accept: audio/wav" --data "{\"text\":\"Hello world\"}" --output text.wav "https://api.us-south.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/eace7388-5b0e-4111-a735-7c1364546698/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_MichaelV3Voice"`

With JavaScript:
I get this error code with or without Access-Control, or no-cors, or *, gives this error: "from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

I also get an Unauthorized error from IBM on user id, which is supposed to be there even though it isn't in cURL, but supposedly any variable will work.

This JavaScript submits a text to voice request to IBM Watson and returns audio. Don't laugh - here is my code:

```
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        /*myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');*/
        myHeaders.append('customer_id', 'blah');
        myHeaders.append('Accept', 'audio/wav');
        myHeaders.append('charset', 'UTF-8');

    fetch('https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_MichaelV3Voice'), {
      apikey: "blahblahblah",
      method: "POST",
      data: "{\"text\":\"Hello world\"}",
      output: "text.wav",
      headers: {myHeaders},
      };
```

I've tried:
myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); this is a wildcard
myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'no-cors');
And leaving this access control header out

Comment: The server has to send back a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header for you to make a ajax request from the browser. If you are trying to address this issue temporarily on your localhost, you can use this chrome extension : Allow CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf. Also if you can share the documentation of the API that you are calling then we **may** be able to help you better as more info is needed to resolve this

Comment: Thanks for your help. Added Access-Control-Allow-Origin to Chrome - same result. I really hate to ask you to look at the documentation - might be better if I just use cURL even though I can't do Tune by Example. I've been writing JavaScript since 1997 - this one is beyond me. 

Basic API and SDK from IBM is at https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech
Github reference is at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk 
For reference, Tune by Example is at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/text-to-speech?topic=text-to-speech-service-features#features-synthesis

Comment: It isn't possible to set cors with JavaScript in any browser. It's a browser setting. I was not able to change settings to get it to work. 

Good news. Tune by example can now be done with cURL. I'm good.